# MySQL architecture optimization - MySQL cluster

Tags: mysql, database-design, storage-engines

gI'm working on a web application with the following structure: We have "customers" and each of these customers have their own "users". 
Each customer (with his users and other data) is completely separated from the others and there is no shared data between them.
Moreover each 'customer' has a different sub-website and all the queries coming from there (either by him or by his users) will always refer to a single customer.id

The database is build in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` ( 
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT 
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE `user` ( 
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `customerID` int(11) unsigned 
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 

CREATE TABLE `blogPost` ( 
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `userID` int(11) unsigned 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I have many tables like 'blogPost' that are connected to the customer via user.

A common query would be something of the sort:

```
SELECT *  
FROM `blogPost` bp 
INNER JOIN `user` u 
ON bp.userID=u.id 
WHERE u.customerID = 324
```

It is noticeable that these joins are expensive and really unnecessary - because the second we enter a sub-website we are only interested in the data that is connected to a particular customer

So the question is how can I improve the Database ? The more I read on the subject the more confused I become-
Is NDB (MySQL Cluster) Storage Engine is the way to go?
Is it preferable to create many different Databases - one for each customer? 
Maybe adding a redundant `customerID` field to `blogPost` ? 
Some other idea? MongoDB ?!

Comment: MySQL Cluster will not solve this, I wonder how you come to this idea? There is a "SELECT *", tables seem very basic, but though about selecting particular columns and not everything?

Comment: The tables have more fields- I only wrote the primary and foreign keys... Usually I select only the relevant columns- this query is just an example to show the join I'm trying to get rid of... I thought MySQL cluster created clusters of rows- so that each customer and related data can be in his own cluster... Maybe that's not true though- I'm looking for any solution and am not limited to MySQL cluster

Answer (score 0):

Firstly lets clear the NDB engine up, MySQL Cluster / NDB is NOT the way to go here, not only does it not offer anything that would help in your situation it actually makes it more complex. Not only will you need a serious amount of resources and a minimum of 3 database servers to run NDB things such as JOINS are still not great within NDB – just don’t go there.

There is nothing wrong with joining tables, RDBMS are designed to do this efficiently. If you’re joining on an index on foreign key this will be both fast and efficient.  What you’re trying to do here is what the vast majority of web databases deal with every day and the majority of them join information together.

You could go one DB per customer but trust me, this will massively increase your database administration work and if you really don’t have to go down this avenue for business reasons etc please don’t.  It’s a nightmare when schema changes happen and when customer x has performance issues but customer y doesn’t – you’ll end up causing yourself a lot of work

Comment: Thanks.. I see what you are saying but I'm worried about tables such as message(id,from_user,to_user,content). 
Let's assume I have only 1000 customers, each customer with 200 users on average- I'll limit the amount of messages per user to 100. So we a have a single table with 1000*200*100 = 20,000,000 records .. Isn't there some more scalable way to go ? [users of different customers cannot send messages to eachother]

Comment: @gilads this questions starts to expand when you bring in scalability - there are things you can do such as partitioning / sharding the database, having an archiving policy etc.  Maybe even a solution that doesn't involve a RDBMS - XML / no SQL etc

Answer (score 0):

> So the question is how can I improve the Database ?

Yes, Joins are expensive. Particularly if (as implied by your create table statements) you have *no indexes*. If this really is the case then you **MUST** add indexes, at least on the primary and foreign keys. (I also note that according to your design you don't store any content for blog posts? Really?

> A common query would be something...

Really? There's something very wrong with your application if your queries don't implement any sort of filtering. If the filtering is implemented as paging and the data is rarely deleted / updated then per-foreign key sequence numbers would be more efficient than global auto-increment ids.

> Is it preferable to create many different Databases

ABSOLUTELY NOT.

Certainly if you've got the physical devices distributing the I/O across different disks will improve I/O performance (assuming that your DBMS is properly configured and your hot data set is too large to fit into memory) in which case you should consider either interleaving the indexes and data filse across different disks and/or using MySQL's built in support for sharding across filesystems.

> Maybe adding a redundant customerID field to blogPost

Maybe.

Clustering is a very good idea for availability and a good idea for performance - but it comes with an overhead in terms of the skills and time needed to set it up and keep it running. You certainly shouldn't be looking at NDB now - after you've exhausted the scope for tuning the single instance, have a lok at synchronous and asynchronous replication.

Start by adding indexes, then tune your DBMS config, then try adding customerID into blogposts, then look at how the files are ditributed across your storage (this looks like a great use case for SSDs).

Comment: 1. I'm unfamiliar with the concept of "query filtering" - whatever do you mean? 
2. You talked about taking the current architecture and tuning it up with different methods- That's great and very helpful but I'm worried about tables such as message(id,from_user,to_user,content). 
Let's assume I have only 1000 customers, each customer with 200 users on average- I'll limit the amount of messages per user to 100. So we a have a single table with 1000*200*100 = 20,000,000 records .. 
Isn't there some more scalable way to go ? [users of different customers cannot send messages to each other]